# How to create a PostgresQL extension inside a testcontainer started by Junit5 and configured by Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, junit5, testcontainers

I have a Spring Boot 3 project where I write integration tests that use test containers to run the PostgreSQL database.
I'd like to introduce fuzzy matching in one endpoint, and thus require the PostgresQL extension pg_trgm.

Furthermore, I read the documentation, but it's still not clear how I'm supposed to do such a thing.

- https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/postgres/ is basically empty.
- https://java.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/ looked promising, but is missing the feature I need.

Following what I found in some [GitHub issue](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/2728), I tried defining a bean in a test configuration, but testcontainer doesn't seem to care:

```
@TestConfiguration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer() {
        var name = DockerImageName
                .parse("localhost/cadonym/database")
                .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("postgres");
        return new PostgreSQLContainer<>(name);
    }
}
```

Where the image is defined by:

```
# This image is meant to be used during development only.
FROM docker.io/library/postgres:15.3

ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_DB=cadonym

RUN echo "CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm" >> /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/pg_trgm.sql
```

While running my test, I could see testcontainer creating containers based on `docker.io/testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1` and `docker.io/library/postgres:15.1`. The custom image isn't used, and the test behavior didn't change despite my test configuration: "function similarity(character varying, character varying) does not exist".

I verified that my configuration is loaded by changing the argument of the call "asCompatibleSubstituteFor" ("postgres") to a random value, and it's indeed loaded, as the aforementioned change stops the context from loading as expected.

Other relevant configuration can be found in my test properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:postgresql:15.1:///integration-tests-db
```

Comment: Either you define a bean in the configuration and use `@ServiceConnection` or the URL but not both. The `url` takes precedence over your container.

Comment: @M.Deinum Indeed, that was the issue. Thanks! Does that mean I now have to import my Configuration in every single class annotated with `@SpringBootTest` ? If I don't do something, Spring will fail to load the datasource as the URL is no longer provided by the properties.

Comment: For reference for other people, the following article from Spring Boot was very helpful: https://spring.io/blog/2023/06/23/improved-testcontainers-support-in-spring-boot-3-1 .

Comment: Creating a base class and have other test classes extend this will fix this.

Comment: Relying on docker-compose support for Spring Boot may help to make it more simple.
You will need to create a docker-compose file and put there a service that is created from your image. The environment variables(user, password etc) will be automatically detected by spring boot once it detects the docker-compose and put to ConnectionDetails.
Please do not forget to put label org.springframework.boot.service-connection: 'library/postgres' for the service as you use extended image for posgres.

Answer (score 0):

The missing part was the annotation @ServiceConnection:

```
package dev.fita.cadonym;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.testcontainers.service.connection.ServiceConnection;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;
import org.testcontainers.utility.DockerImageName;


@TestConfiguration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ServiceConnection
    public static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer() {
        return new PostgreSQLContainer<>(DockerImageName
                .parse("localhost/cadonym/database")
                .asCompatibleSubstituteFor("postgres"))
                .withUsername("api")
                .withDatabaseName("cadonym");
    }

}
```

Comment: Though now that I think of it, since then I started using Flyway through Spring Boot to apply my DDL (including installing pg_trgm), thus I don't need a custom image anymore.